# Adding items to Unity top panel

Tags: 16.04, unity, suspend, hibernate

I'm looking for a way to add items to the unity top panel in Ubuntu 16.04.
E.g. there is the dropdown menu where you can the system settings or switch account.
I would like to either place an item there or just place a new item in the panel.

The reason for that is, that the standard "suspend" which I got there is the pm-hibernate, but I would like to have a button for pm-suspend as it is much faster

Comment: Panel items are called "indicators". You can write app-indicators yourself, e.g. with a short Python script. There should be a few examples to be found on this site or with your preferred search engine.

Comment: Thanks, seems to work - should I delete the question now?

Comment: If you want, you are free to do so, but it would be much greater if you posted an answer detailing what you found out and how you solved your issue instead, so that the community may profit from it. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice :) I'll try to do so within the next few days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Byte Commander already pointed to, the answer is quite easy, there are very simple explanations about creating indicators, as e.g. [this](http://candidtim.github.io/appindicator/2014/09/13/ubuntu-appindicator-step-by-step.html) one in Python, but there are many more e.g. in C, C# etc as you can read [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators)